# Finding the rule that has overriden another via cascade?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome via the developer tools we can see lines through rules that have been overridden by other CSS rules.  Is it possible to find the rules that is doing the overriding via the developer tools?

Comment: it's the first one without line through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]If you have dev tools that opens on the right side of your page, there should be a left side and a right side to the Styles tab. On the right side of that tab you can scroll down until you find the attribute you wish to see under Filter (it is alphabetical). If you expand that attribute, you can see all of the rules applying to it, including the one it is using and all others that have been superseded.